# Nginx: How to set expiration for 404 responses?

Tags: nginx, cache, http-headers, http-status-code-404

My nginx server acts as a proxy for another server, which sometimes returns 404s.
I want the 404 responses to be cacheable, just like 200 responses.

However, I cannot use `expires`, because the [documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule#expires) states that:

> `expires` works only for 200, 204, 301, 302, and 304 responses.

Note that caching of non-200 responses is [perfectly possible](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/ietf-http-wg/2009OctDec/0088.html) according to the HTTP spec.

**So how can I set an expiration date on 404 responses?**

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1. Modify another server to provide caching headers.
2. Use [headers_more](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module. It allows add headers to error http responses, but you'll have to recompile nginx.
3. Use [Lua module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#header_filter_by_lua).

---

#### Original answer

It's impossible to cache error pages on client (browser)

Probably you want to cache response from another server and it possible with `proxy_cache` directive. Also take a look at `proxy_cache_valid` directive.

Comment: Why would caching error pages on the client be impossible?
For instance, it would totally make sense to cache a 410 GONE response.

Comment: OK, you convinced me. I've changed my mind and the answer.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh 410 _is_ cacheable by default; 404 _is not_.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Where does it say that 410 is cacheable and 404 not?
Note that `expires` (nginx-specific) only works for 200, 204, 301, 302, 304.

Comment: @alexeyten Thanks, but does `headers_more` allow me to do the date arithmetic and if so, how?

Comment: @RubenVerborgh [RFC 2616 section 13.4.](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-13.4)

Comment: @MichaelHampton The RFC says "A response received with a status code of 200, 203, 206, 300, 301 or 410 MAY be stored by a cache and used in reply to a subsequent request” but does not say that 404 is not cacheable by default. (But even if it did, that's what I want to do: I want to cache the 404 responses of this server.)

Comment: @RubenVerborgh Um, yes it does, in the very next paragraph.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh, unfortunately, no. See [limitations](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule#Limitations).

Comment: @RubenVerborgh, updated post. You could use Lua module and have all the power of lua to calculate dates.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Next paragraph: “A response received with any other status code (e.g. status codes 302 and 307) MUST NOT be returned in a reply to a subsequent request unless there are cache-control directives or another header(s) that explicitly allow it.”
So it is cacheable.

Comment: @alexeyten Thanks but I'd need a more specific answer. It currently explains different ways to add headers, not how to set Expired on a 404 response.

Comment: @RubenVerborgh I said it was not cacheable _by default_, which is still true.